# PHP code to create MySQL table from CSV upload

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I know this has been asked before, and believe me, I have searched the web for days to try and find code that works.

I have a CSV file that is created from MS Access that I use to update an online calendar daily. Currently, I am going into phpMyAdmin to drop the old table, then upload the CSV and rename it to "CALENDAR". I want to create a PHP page that will automatically do this. With one click access will export a CSV and open up a webpage on my server that will upload the CSV file from "C:\accessExport\CALENDAR.csv" this CSV file has the field names in the first row.

I have come very close, alas, the code that I found does not work. It is just shows a blank webpage. I have had this problem when using other developers PHP codes before and I have found that the problem was occurring because the given code was using double quotes when single quotes were needed. If you could take a look at my code or suggest a better method, I would really appreciate it.

Here is a link to the code I am using:
http://websitedevelopmentind.blogspot.com/2014/01/create-mysql-table-from-csv-file-using.html

Thanks!

```
<?php

 //table Name
$tableName = "CALENDAR";
//database name
$dbName = "CertCalendar";


 $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db($dbName) or die(mysql_error());

//get the first row fields
$fields = "";
$fieldsInsert = "";
if (($handle = fopen("C:\accessExport\CALENDAR.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
if(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $fieldsInsert .= '(';
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        $fieldsInsert .=($c==0) ? '' : ', ';
        $fieldsInsert .="`".$data[$c]."`";
        $fields .="`".$data[$c]."` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,";
    }

    $fieldsInsert .= ')';
}


//drop table if exist
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$tableName."'"))>=1) {
  mysql_query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `'.$tableName.'`') or die(mysql_error());
}

//create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `".$tableName."` (
          `".$tableName."Id` int(100) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          ".$fields."
          PRIMARY KEY (`".$tableName."Id`)
        ) ";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

            $num = count($data);
            $fieldsInsertvalues="";
            //get field values of each row
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                $fieldsInsertvalues .=($c==0) ? '(' : ', ';
                $fieldsInsertvalues .="'".$data[$c]."'";
            }
            $fieldsInsertvalues .= ')';
            //insert the values to table
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tableName." ".$fieldsInsert."  VALUES   ".$fieldsInsertvalues;
            mysql_query($sql,$conn);   
    }
    echo 'Table Created';   
}

fclose($handle);

}

?>
```

Comment: Yet another so-called 'tutorial' that should be removed from the internet altogether, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: I have already tried replacing mysql_* with mysqli_* and it does not work. I am aware of this, the tutorial was created less than 2 months ago. Please provide a solution in lieu of commenting on bad/outdated syntax.

Comment: Unless you post the code you are actually using, I doubt anyone will help you. People here don't like debugging code from external links, especially if you've already modified it.

Comment: there you go, have at it dog

Comment: After all that, the code you have posted works fine for me... Do you have error reporting enabled? I can't see why else you would just get a blank screen.

Comment: Although it's using an insecure way of accessing a database, it was a lot of help for what I needed... I just converted to PDO.  Thanks dude!  +1